# Compilation error when overloading method with delegate argument

Tags: c#, delegates, overloading

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting a compilation error, when using a method overload that refers to delegates with two different method signatures.

Can someone explain to me why I get a compilation error on the second time I call `MyMethod`, but don't get a compilation error the first time I call `MyMethod`?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // This is fine.
    MyMethod(ProvideIntValue);

    // error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
    // 'Program.MyMethod(Program.DelegateInt)' and 'Program.MyMethod(Program.DelegateFloat)'
    MyMethod(ProvideFloatValue);
}

static int ProvideIntValue()
{ 
    return 1;
}

static float ProvideFloatValue()
{ 
    return 2f;
}

static void MyMethod(DelegateInt delegateInt)
{ 
}

static void MyMethod(DelegateFloat delegateFloat)
{ 
}

delegate int DelegateInt();
delegate float DelegateFloat();
```

I know I can avoid the compilation error, by casting the second call as `MyMethod((DelegateFloat) ProvideFloatValue)`, but I fail to see why such a cast is necessary.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NCOv2e).

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KN7lRD @Sweeper

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Might be a compiler bug in some particular version of the compiler.

Comment: The problem occurs using Visual Studio 2017 Professional. I've reproduced the problem on another computer with VS2017 Community version 15.9.31 (Currently the latest version of VS2017). I can confirm that building the same project on VS2019 doesn't produce the build error.